# how to migrate complete website from magento 1 to magento 2?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2

Recently I'm trying to migrate our website from Magento1 to Magento 2. I want to move complete website, where we have lot of third party custom extensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can only migrate data from `magento1` to `magento2`

you cannot migrate whole extension to `magento2` ,

you have to recode those extension for `magento2` or ask extension providor to create those extension for `magento2`

`magento1` and `magento2` has different file and code structure so you only can migrate data not code

you can refer this post for migrate your site:  https://community.magento.com/t5/Version-Upgrades/How-to-upgrade-Magento-1-9-2-to-2-0/td-p/23920

Comment: @ManjunathMg you are always welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you have to install migration tool please refer this site and follow the steps described.
Very easily your site will migrate to magento-2.
Make sure your magento 2 is installed using composer.

Below is the link to follow --

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool.html